# An errant line on a simple plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why is there a horizontal line in the following plot? If it were plotted on the Cartesian plane, the horizontal line would be drawn along the positive *x*-axis. Every command is to draw a semicircle or to color a semicircle.

The figure is composed of 18 semicircles - nine of which are above the *x*-axis and nine of which are below the *x*-axis. Every arc from a semicircle above the *x*-axis should align with an arc below the *x*-axis. These arcs don't quite align, though.

```
\documentclass{amsart}


\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}




\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm,y=0.25cm]

\draw (-9,0) arc (180:0:9);
\path[fill=Purple] (-9,0) arc (180:0:9) -- (9,0) -- (-9,0);
\draw (-9,0) arc (180:0:8);
\path[fill=Orchid] (-9,0) arc (180:0:8) -- (7,0) -- (-9,0);
\draw (-9,0) arc (180:0:7);
\path[fill=blue] (-9,0) arc (180:0:7) -- (5,0) -- (-9,0);
\draw (-9,0) arc (180:0:6);
\path[fill=green] (-9,0) arc (180:0:6) -- (3,0) -- (-9,0);
\draw (-9,0) arc (180:0:5);
\path[fill=yellow] (-9,0) arc (180:0:5) -- (1,0) -- (-9,0);
\draw (-9,0) arc (180:0:4);
\path[fill=orange] (-9,0) arc (180:0:4) -- (-1,0) -- (-9,0);
\draw (-9,0) arc (180:0:3);
\path[fill=RedOrange] (-9,0) arc (180:0:3) -- (-3,0) -- (-9,0);
\draw (-9,0) arc (180:0:2);
\path[fill=Red] (-9,0) arc (180:0:2) -- (-5,0) -- (-9,0);
\draw (-9,0) arc (180:0:1);
\path[fill=Mahogany] (-9,0) arc (180:0:1) -- (-7,0) -- (-9,0);


\draw (-9,0) arc (180:360:9);
\path[fill=Mahogany] (-9,0) arc (180:360:9) -- (18,0) -- (-9,0);
\draw (-7,0) arc (180:360:8);
\path[fill=Red] (-7,0) arc (180:360:8) -- (18,0) -- (-7,0);
\draw (-5,0) arc (180:360:7);
\path[fill=RedOrange] (-5,0) arc (180:360:7) -- (18,0) -- (-5,0);
\draw (-3,0) arc (180:360:6);
\path[fill=orange] (-3,0) arc (180:360:6) -- (18,0) -- (-3,0);
\draw (-1,0) arc (180:360:5);
\path[fill=yellow] (-1,0) arc (180:360:5) -- (18,0) -- (-1,0);
\draw (1,0) arc (180:360:4);
\path[fill=green] (1,0) arc (180:360:4) -- (18,0) -- (1,0);
\draw (3,0) arc (180:360:3);
\path[fill=blue] (3,0) arc (180:360:3) -- (18,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (5,0) arc (180:360:2);
\path[fill=Orchid] (5,0) arc (180:360:2) -- (18,0) -- (5,0);
\draw (7,0) arc (180:360:1);
\path[fill=Purple] (7,0) arc (180:360:1) -- (18,0) -- (7,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you put two filling area next to each other, a "territory" will appear.

Comment: Yes, when I removed the path-filling commands, the arcs did align.

Comment: Is there another code that would render the same figure?

Comment: Why is there a purple horizontal line drawn from "(1,0)"? It seems that the `\path[fill=Purple] (7,0) arc (180:360:1) -- (18,0) -- (7,0);` command drew it.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire, see my answer. does it gives what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Zarko Is the only difference between the codes is your code used the `very thin` to draw the arcs?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire, no. compare code and you will see, that each shape is drawn with single closed line filled with selected color. `very thin` line i select to better see the edges of the shapes, especially in the area where they are very close to each other or even overlapping.

Comment: Yes, in your code you do not draw the diameter of the semicircles. I do not know why drawing the diameters or using the default `line width=0.4pt` would make the upper half not align with the lower half ... but your code gives me what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if this code reproduces your figure in the desired form:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm,y=0.25cm, very thin]
\draw[fill=Mahogany]    (-9,0) arc (180:0:9) arc (360:180:9);
\draw[fill=Red]         (-9,0) arc (180:0:9) arc (360:180:8) arc (0:180:1);
\draw[fill=RedOrange]   (-9,0) arc (180:0:9) arc (360:180:7) arc (0:180:2);
\draw[fill=orange]      (-9,0) arc (180:0:9) arc (360:180:6) arc (0:180:3);
\draw[fill=yellow]      (-9,0) arc (180:0:9) arc (360:180:5) arc (0:180:4);
\draw[fill=green]       (-9,0) arc (180:0:9) arc (360:180:4) arc (0:180:5);
\draw[fill=blue]        (-9,0) arc (180:0:9) arc (360:180:3) arc (0:180:6);
\draw[fill=Orchid]      (-9,0) arc (180:0:9) arc (360:180:2) arc (0:180:7);
\draw[fill=Purple]      (-9,0) arc (180:0:9) arc (360:180:1) arc (0:180:8);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*: each shape is drawn with a single closed line filled with a selected color. A very thin line is added around the edges of the shapes, especially in the area where they are very close to each other or even overlapping.